# TypeScript - declare truly global variable to access directly, no window, global or globalThis

Tags: javascript, typescript, global-variables

I want to pass some environment variables to a front-end app. They are passed via replace as part of the build process, so for example:
`if (ENV_IS_PRODUCTION) { ... }` will evaluate to: `if (false) { ... }`  in the compiled bundle (so it can be stripped completely by the minifier).

Now I need some way to tell TypeScript that `ENV_IS_PRODUCTION` is a boolean. I want to use it directly, `window.ENV_IS_PRODUCTION` would evaluate to `window.false` so it's not an option.

The furthest I came with it is to declare it locally:

```
declare const ENV_IS_PRODUCTION: boolean;
```

But I have no idea how to declare it globally. I tried putting the above local definition into globals.d.ts but it doesn't work. And again, I cannot use window, global, or globalThis. It has to be accessed directly as a variable, without having to import it and without using window/global.

Comment: How about creating some `ENV` interface? And use it as `ENV.IS_PRODUCTION`?

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong. I have just put this to globals.d.ts: `declare global { interface ENV { IS_PRODUCTION: boolean } }`  and when I try to use it I get ENV only refers to a type, but is used as a value. Same with: `declare interface ENV { IS_PRODUCTION: boolean }` And if I tried to declare it as a var, it wouldn't pick it at all.

Comment: In another answer I have found a link to a project that has this working properly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwcfd5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts but I cannot get it to work with my project, putting: `declare const ENV_IS_PRODUCTION: boolean;` to globals.d.ts won't work for me.

Comment: It turns out it's a problem with vscode. If I define it in globals.d.ts or if I add it to a file in typeRoots directory, it compiles. It's just that vscode seem to be unaware of it.

Comment: Try re-open the editor. Sometimes VS code does not catch changes in d.ts files and requires restart

Comment: Yep, it seems to work. Now I just need to deal with Eslint not catching it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it turns out the local definition put into globals.d.ts should work. I just had some problems with VS Code not picking it up (worked after the restart, but I probably didn't notice as Eslint gave an error separately - which I still haven't solved but it's rather minor).

So the solution, in this case, is to simply put this in globals.d.ts:

```
declare const ENV_IS_PRODUCTION: boolean;
```

#### Update:

The Eslint error that caused the confusion was because Eslnt doesn't seem to recognize types defined like this. The solution is to disable no-undef rule for all TypeScript files - it is redundant anyway, as tsc will not allow an undefined variable anyway. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/342

#### Update 2:

I will add that another reason it didn't work for me initially is that there appears to be something off with globals.d.ts When I had this definition, and a declaration about Window object, in one globals.d.ts - it didn't work too. I settled on using `compilerOptions.typeRoots` and put the type files there instead of using globals.d.ts and it's working fine.

So the best solution is:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/types"
    ]
   }
}
```

**src/types/env.d.ts**

```
declare const ENV: {
  IS_PRODUCTION: boolean
};
```